# Envelope of a real function consisting of a complex function and its conjugate

Tags: derivatives, complex-numbers, several-complex-variables, envelope

For a real function $f(x)=A(x)e^{ix}+\overline{A}(x)e^{-ix}$, where $\overline{A}$ represents complex conjugate of $A$. Note that $A(x)$ itself is a complex function $A(x)=A_r(x)+i A_i(x)$. It seems that the envelope of $f(x)$ should be $\pm 2\vert A \vert$, where $\vert \cdot \vert$ repersents the modulus of a complex number. That is, the envelope of $f(x)$ is double amplitude of $A$ if $f$ can be written as $A(x)e^{ix}+c.c.$

Now, I am confusing with the envelope of the real function $g=ff_x$ since it cannot be written in a similar form.
Substituting $f(x)$ into $g=ff_x$, one obtains $g=A(A_x+iA)e^{2ix}+A\overline{A}_x+c.c.$, where c.c. repersents the complex conjugate of the preceding terms.
How can I express the amplitude of the envelope of $g$ with $A$, $\overline{A}$ and their derivatives?

For the 1st term and its conjugate, the envelope should be $\pm 2 \vert A(A_x+iA)\vert$. But I do not know how to include the 2nd term and its c.c. Can anyone please give me some suggestions? Thank you in advance!

Comment: MathJax tip: `\overline{A}(x)` produces $\overline{A}(x)$.

Comment: @TheoBendit thanks for the tip :)

Comment: I am unsure on what the envelope of a complex function is. I tried reading [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Envelope_(waves)) but I am still unsure

Comment: Hi, thank you for your link! Here, the "envelope" means the envelope of the amplitude of the high-frequency signal, which includes real and imaginary parts.

Comment: @Teresa Lisbon, actually I am not sure whether it should be $2[\vert A (A_x+iA) \vert + Re[AA_x]]$ or $2[\vert A (A_x+iA) \vert + \vert AA_x \vert]$?

Comment: @Enter I am still a bit confused. So for example I have a function, say $f(x) = \sin x$ on the real line. What would its envelope be? I want a definition that lets me compute the envelope for a few examples. The problem is, I'm not really sure how a function is a high frequency signal, and what its amplitude would be. The Wikipedia post doesn't clarify that either, unfortunately.

Comment: @TeresaLisbon I think for the particular case of $\sin x$ its envelope should be its amplitude, here, it is $\pm 1$. In this example, it is a pure real function (with Im=0), so there is no coefficient of $2$.